# Really really strange delegate issue with quickBlox iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, delegates, quickblox

I'm currently using the new quickBlox 2.0 SDK in my app. I'm testing both on an iphone 5s (i0S 8) and an iphone 4s (iOS 7.1.2).

I'm running the **same code on both phones**. The delegates get called correctly for the iphone 5s version every time. However, when I perform the **same actions on the iphone 4s, the delegates never get called**.

Do anyone know what could be causing this?

In the log, I can clearly see that I'm getting data:

```
 QBChat/didReceiveMessage: <message xmlns="jabber:client" type="qbvideochat_acceptCall" from="1645510-14896@chat.quickblox.com" to="1645761-14896@chat.quickblox.com" id="1441282327"><extraParams xmlns="jabber:client"><sessionID>434152105.631015</sessionID><callType>1</callType></extraParams></message>
[QBVideoChat didReceiveVideoMessage:] -> Message: <message xmlns="jabber:client" type="qbvideochat_acceptCall" from="1645510-14896@chat.quickblox.com" to="1645761-14896@chat.quickblox.com" id="1441282327"><extraParams xmlns="jabber:client"><sessionID>434152105.631015</sessionID><callType>1</callType></extraParams></message>, MessageType: qbvideochat_acceptCall
[QBVideoChat didReceiveVideoMessage:] -> Accepted call
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does it behave in the Simulator?  You should probably try to see if it's the iOS version or the device type that's causing the difference.

Can you debug to see if the delegate is nil?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your advice. It seems that the delegate methods are being called correctly on ios 8, but not being called in ios7.1. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: debugging to see if the delegate is nil would be a good step.  If it's nil for some reason then the reason you aren't getting the messages is because there's no object to pass them to.  If it's not nil then something else weird is going on.  This is tough to diagnose without seeing more code.  You might want to see if there's a forum for that particular framework (QBVideoChat?)

Comment: thanks Kirk- your suggestions pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally pinpointed the cause of the issue.

Source of issue:

In viewcontroller 1, in viewDidDisappear I set [QBChat instance].delegate = nil

In viewcontroller 2, in viewDidAppear I set [QBChat instance].delegate = self

Solution:

Remove viewDidDisappear [QBChat instance].delegate = nil in viewcontroller 1.

I mistakenly though that b/c the [QBChat instance] was a singleton, it could be reset in the next VC.

This was super tricky for me because the original code works perfectly on iOS 8.